# Calculate new (x, y) coordinates after transform & transform-origin?

Tags: javascript, matrix, coordinates, transform, css-transforms

I've got this simple fiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/eUSep/

As you can see, I'm scaling up my `test1` div and specifying a new origin. How can I calculate the new position (top, left) of `test2` after the transformation? It must be calculated off of the origin and the scale, but I haven't been able to get it right.

At first I thought I could do it by calculating the height and width *change* (based on the current scale and previous scale), and subtracting half of that from the current `left`, then adding the other half onto the `width` (pseudo code):

```
var left = current_left - (width_change / 2);
var top = current_top - (height_change / 2 );

var right = current_left + width + (width_change / 2);
var bottom = current_top + height + (height_change / 2);
```

But that doesn't take the origin into account, and I think this would only work if the origin was in the exact center each time. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually appears that [Jquery Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) will do the work for me.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eUSep/1/

I can get the position before and after the transformation to see the change:

```
var pos = $('#test2').position();
```